# Can someone translate these Seal Characters to Mandarin? (Characters identified: 五世)

Tags: seal

[image]

Can anyone help me translate these Seal Characters into classical/modern Chinese characters?  They are on my neighbor's furniture brought from the Philippines. I have 12 more pictures, but this site seems to just allow one picture.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The characters are 五世 (Five generations?)

Comment: Thank you! Is there some way I can post the other pictures all together?

Comment: @JwangChyunHou stitch them all into one picture